# Azure Blob Store Content-length

Tags: azure, curl, azure-blob-storage

The azure blob store seems to incorrectly set the content length when performing byte range requests. Previous versions do not support open ended requests, so I thought that by upping to the most recent version my issue would be solved (2015-04-05).

Here I have performed a GET request for a file in an azure blob and print out the headers. I expect the Content-Length to be the remaining 255 bytes, but instead I find the entire file size (15601108255)

`(server-1)➜  server-1 git:(faster_calls) ✗ curl -I http://ga4ghstore.blob.core.windows.net/testing/HG00096.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20120522.bam --header "x-ms-version: 2015-04-05" --range 15601108000-
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 15601108255
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-MD5: M26lWRO8Jhtyh1vSWXUwRg==
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 18:30:11 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "0x8D36E00CD845EC7"
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 2bf052dc-0001-013d-256d-a5a7a7000000
x-ms-version: 2015-04-05
x-ms-write-protection: false
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-lease-state: available
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
Date: Tue, 03 May 2016 18:55:49 GMT`

The range request appears to be handled properly, as in, the returned payload is of the expected size, however, compare the headers with what is returned from Amazon for the same file. The "content-length" header is the expected "255".

`(server-1)➜  server-1 git:(faster_calls) ✗ curl -I --range 15601108000- http://s3.amazonaws.com/1000genomes/phase3/data/HG00096/alignment/HG00096.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20120522.bam

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
x-amz-id-2: w6IO4ezWj2BBTkHA09D9gNRZgkmAQJ8khqc6O9t+Xr+xHmZKvwVTNd0vLCpaVcKoVl/2jZUskug=
x-amz-request-id: CE8F86CD94173F51
Date: Tue, 03 May 2016 18:59:22 GMT
x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs: uid:1000/gname:ubuntu/uname:ubuntu/gid:1000/mode:33204/mtime:1431500614/atime:1431500346/ctime:1431500614
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 May 2015 06:57:53 GMT
ETag: "efd6d57b0f27974f6845f4e67a99c1a6-117"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 15601108000-15601108254/15601108255
Content-Type: application/gzip; charset=binary
Content-Length: 255
Server: AmazonS3`

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the same command using cUrl on my machine and if I understand it right, when you execute cUrl command with `-I` option you're essentially making a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET` request. Essentially your command is making [`Get Blob Properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179394.aspx) REST API call which doesn't return the data.

So the response is correct in case of Azure because `Content-Length` response header should tell you the size of the blob. If you want to see the size returned, you would need to make the cUrl request with `-G` (Get) parameter. and then you will see only 255 bytes are returned.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav! That helps! It seems Amazon and Microsoft implement the HEAD request differently. I did curl -vG and found the 206 with the proper Content-Length.

Comment: Though, I still believe this is a bug: "The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request."(http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)